# How to discipline our 16-month-old son who stopped listening to us and started to misbehave?

Tags: toddler, discipline

Our 1-year- and 4-month-old son's behavior was perfect before - he always listened to us. But now it seems that he takes a completely different direction.

For example, we explain to him that touching a socket is dangerous, but he keeps doing it. Or he starts to beat other people and so on...

Maybe it’s a special period? He is teething and has a seasonal cold. How should we behave? How to make our child do the right thing?

Comment: I'm not familiar with 1,4 notation. I guess that's 1 year 4 month. [linked](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/31060/how-to-stop-a-one-year-old-from-biting?rq=1)

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt That's probably it.  A lot of non-English languages use the period and comma for numbers the opposite way that English does.  So in English one thousand four hundred eighty two and three tenths (1,482.3) would be written as 1.482,3 in some of those languages.  So I'm guessing 1,4 year old means something like 1 year and 4 months or 1.4 years old.  Regardless, its about same age no matter how you interpret that.

Comment: Don't confuse punishment with discipline. At this age you can't reason with him,  so you're going to want to use redirection as much as you can.  Instill discipline by making a game or of following simple instructions,  and praise/reward him for obedience. Recognize that he will do dangerous things and make mistakes,  and it's all part of growing up and learning.

Answer (score 3):

1) Kids push boundaries at this age.  It's what they do.  He is **supposed** to be exploring.  You can't possibly reason him out of exploring, nor should you.

2) A child that young doesn't understand when you say "That's dangerous".  You can teach him by example that if he tries to touch "dangerous" things, he gets picked up immediately.  And you do your best to keep unsafe things away from your child's environment.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, congratulations for the young boy.

This is a phase, he's challenging the limits and seeing how far he can go, try to keep calm and explain why he can't do certain things. 
They still do not have the perception of danger.

If he messes up everything, for example, instead of punishing or trying to make him clean, volunteer to help him, say: Can I help you with the toys?
It gives them the feeling that's he's controlling the situation and it becomes more controlled behavior.
Another thing you can do is create a reward for something he does well, "if you eat everything we'll see that movie you like." or something else.
On top of all this, if he's been sick it's normal for him to be more annoyed,when we feel sick when we feel bad too, don't we?
Keep calm, show him that you love him and everything will be resolved.
Good luck :)

Comment: It's generally not considered  great idea to tie eating to other rewards.  Kids should be encouraged to eat as much as they want, and to stop when they are full.  Also, a child this young isn't going to understand a causal connection between two events happening days apart.

Comment: @swbarnes sorry but i disagre, what isn't correct is offer food as a reward